# how to get the delta of swipe/ draging touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to calculate the delta between a swipe gesture or dragging gesture. what I want to do is to get this delta and then to use it as velocity (by adding time var). I really get confused about how should I do this - via `touchesMoved` or via `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. also, I don't really understand the difference between them. right now I set and get the first touch on the screen but I don't know how to get the last one so I can calculate the vector. can anyone help me with that?

right now I'm doing that via `touchesBega`n and `touchesEnded`, I'm not sure if its the right and the better way, here is my code so far:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var start: CGPoint?
var end: CGPoint?


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {        

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
    self.start = touch.location(in: self)
    print("start point: ", start!)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
    self.end = touch.location(in: self)
    print("end point: ", end!)

    let deltax:CGFloat = ((self.start?.x)! - (self.end?.x)!)
    let deltay:CGFloat = ((self.start?.y)! - (self.end?.y)!)
    print(UInt(deltax))
    print(UInt(deltay))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect swipe gestures using the built-in touch handlers of SpriteKit or you can implement a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. The following is an example of how to detect swipe gestures using SpriteKit's touch handlers:

First, define the variables and constants...

Define the starting point and time of the initial touch.

```
var touchStart: CGPoint?
var startTime : TimeInterval?
```

Define constants that specify the characteristics of the swipe gesture. By changing these constants, you can detect the difference between a swipe, drag, or flick.

```
let minSpeed:CGFloat = 1000
let maxSpeed:CGFloat = 5000
let minDistance:CGFloat = 25
let minDuration:TimeInterval = 0.1
```

In `touchesBegan`, store the starting point and time of the initial touch

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touchStart = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    startTime = touches.first?.timestamp
}
```

In `touchesEnded`, calculate the gesture's distance, duration, and speed. Compare these value against the constants to determine if the gesture was a swipe.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touchStart = self.touchStart else {
        return
    }
    guard let startTime = self.startTime else {
        return
    }
    guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {
        return
    }
    guard let time = touches.first?.timestamp else {
        return
    }
    var dx = location.x - touchStart.x
    var dy = location.y - touchStart.y
    // Distance of the gesture
    let distance = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    if distance >= minDistance {
        // Duration of the gesture
        let deltaTime = time - startTime
        if deltaTime > minDuration {
            // Speed of the gesture
            let speed = distance / CGFloat(deltaTime)
            if speed >= minSpeed && speed <= maxSpeed {
                // Normalize by distance to obtain unit vector
                dx /= distance
                dy /= distance
                // Swipe detected
                print("Swipe detected with speed = \(speed) and direction (\(dx), \(dy)")
            }
        }
    }
    // Reset variables
    touchStart = nil
    startTime = nil
}
```